# c# preprocessor directives based on web publish profile

Tags: c#, compilation

I have a test and production web server.  My project has a piece of code that I would like in place on the test server, but not in place on the production server.

`#if (DEBUG)` doesn't work, because I prefer both to be published in RELEASE mode.

Is there any way to set up a preprocessor directive based on which web Publish profile is being used?

Comment: VS2010? Starting from VS2012 the publish profile allows you to specify the corresponding build configuration. That completes avoiding the issue you want to resolve and is a better approach. http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TinyHappyFeatures3PublishingImprovementsChainedConfigTransformsAndDeployingASPNETAppsFromTheCommandLine.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way to accomplish this is to create separate build configurations for each of the environments you need to publish to. You can clone your new build configurations from Release. Then, in the project settings, enter the name of your build configuration in the Conditional compilation symbols box.

So, for example, we have a Stage build configuration which is identical to Release except it defines the STAGE compiler constant. Then, in the code, you can use #if (STAGE) checks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are like me wondering where MS moved everything, on VS2022, here it is:
[image]